# How do low/critical battery alarms and their corresponding triggers work on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, battery

On my old Windows XP laptop, when I enter the **control panel**, click **power options**, and then go to the **alarms** tab, I can wander around the settings for the low and critical battery alarms, including their battery percentage level and their corresponding triggers.

When I enter the **alarms** tab, this is what I see on my computer screen:

> ### Low battery alarm
>
> - Power level: 10%
> - Notification: Text + Sound
> - Action: No action
> - Run program: None
>
> ### Critical battery alarm
>
> - Power level: 3%
> - Notification: Text + Sound
> - Action: Hibernate
> - Run program: None

Now, when I compare the settings on my new Windows 10 laptop, I see this:

> ### Low battery
>
> - Power level: 10%
> - Notification: Text + Sound
> - Action: No action
> - Run program: None
>
> ### Reserve battery
>
> - Power level: 7%
> - Notification: Text + Sound
> - Action: No action
> - Run program: None
>
> ### Critical battery
>
> - Power level: 5%
> - Action: Hibernate

On my new Windows 10 laptop, when running on battery and the level reaches 10%, it shows a low battery message and the computer makes a sound effect.  The reserve level is on 7% and my laptop will make a more dramatic sound and show a bigger message when the battery drops to this level.  A few minutes later, the laptop will hit 5% and will go to hibernation.

How does this work on Windows XP?

(I see that there is no "reserve" level on Windows XP, so it will trigger the alarm on 3% and then hibernate the laptop immediately afterwards?)

Comment: What's wrong with you running the battery down on your Windows XP and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XP for your settings above, will give you a warning at 10% (visual and/or sound):

> [image]

And then at 3% it will hibernate immediately after it gives you another warning (visual and/or sound).

> [image]

The difference in 10% and 3% normally gives you enough time to plug in the AC Adapter. That is how I did it when I had XP many years ago.

A defective battery (so old as above) may just shut off. I have seen that as well