# How do I get my Windows 10 laptop to trigger the critical battery notification on 3% and then hibernate immediately after?

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp

I would like to get the alarms and triggers to act exactly the same as in Windows XP.

- On Windows ≥7, the battery alarms and its triggers are in default:

  - Low battery alarm: 10%, text + sound
  - Low battery action: Do nothing
  - Critical battery alarm: 7%, text + sound
  - Critical battery action level: 5%
  - Critical battery action: Hibernate
- On Windows XP, it was slightly different:

  - Low battery alarm: 10%, text + sound
  - Low battery action: Do nothing
  - Critical battery alarm: 3%, text + sound
  - Critical battery action: Hibernate, **perform action immediately once the alarm sounds**

The important difference is that Windows XP has the critical level set to 3% and puts the computer [into hibernation immediately](https://superuser.com/a/1534093/1136553) after the critical battery alarm notification pops up.

How do I get the low/critical battery alarms and their corresponding actions to do the same as Windows XP did?

Comment: With the default settings you will get the Reserve Battery Level flashing at 7% followed by Critical Battery Action at 5%. Why is that not good enough (or better)?

Comment: *Well, I get low battery notification popping up on 10%, then very low battery flashing on 7%, and finally the empty battery hibernation on 5%.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening the Run box (Win + R) and typing `powercfg.cpl`, hitting enter should open Power Options.

Then, clicking the selected plan "Edit Plan Settings" followed by "Change advanced power settings" will open another window.

In this new window, scroll to the bottom and expand Battery. You can change actions and thresholds there.

I have recorded a video of me doing so for further clarity [here](https://gfycat.com/harmlessfeminineblackwidowspider)

[Mirror link](https://streamable.com/3opwl) as Gfycat doesn't seem to work for now

Comment: (Reposted as a *comment* due to lack of *reputation*) If you don't find what you were looking for in Power settings following QuickishFM's advice, you can download this standalone freeware called PowerSettingsExplorer (http://www.mediafire.com/file/wt37sbsejk7iepm/PowerSettingsExplorer.zip/file), from which you can show/hide and set a multitude of less-known power management settings for Windows. (Of